# JavaScript object accessing itself from within its property by its own name

Tags: javascript

Please look at below codes:

Case 1:

```
var a = {
    b: function(){
        console.log(a)
    },
    c:1
};
```

Case 2:

```
var a = {
    b:a,
    c:1
};
```

Now when I write this :

```
a.b() // for first
console.log(a.b) // for 2nd
```

I get result:

```
{c:1}
```

I have two questions:

1. How does the property 'b' of its parent 'a' can access its parent 'a' by its name, i.e. 'a'?
2. If it's accessing it, then why doesn't it show all the properties of 'a'?

Comment: Your second case is wrong. it will print `undefined` (because `a` is not defined at the time you define `b`).

Comment: In Chrome console, it logs `{c:1}`. but if you click the arrow to expand it, you will see it also includes `b: function`

Comment: You don't have to run both examples at the same time. Both examples must be taken as separate codes (that's what i've understood at least).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your second example, you will get `undefined`, because at the time the object gets defined, `a` is undefined.

In your first example, `a` is created in the global scope, thats why your `console.log` will show the whole `a` object with it's functions and properties.

Comment: note, you can make the second example work by using a getter like `var a = {
    get b (){ return a},
    c:1
};`